# Program compiles but wont run

Tags: java, command-line

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm taking an AP Computer Science course to learn more. I was tasked with modifying some code from a program called *GridWorld*, but the problem is I can't tell if I made the right modifications because my code won't run.

I have to link the file to a jar file called *gridworld.jar* on the command line, and I was able to compile, and it generated a class file, but when I tried to run it, it said it couldn't find or load the main class.

I've looked all over for an answer and I can't find it even though it might be a simple beginner question.

This [link](http://apcentral.collegeboard.com/apc/members/repository/ap07_gridworld_installation_guide.pdf) has a description of how to compile and run the code, but I've tried what it says to no avail, so maybe you guys can understand it. (The file I want to run is in *C:\GridWorldCode\projects\firstProject* and it's called *BugRunner*. The jar file is in *C:\GridWorldCode*.)

This is what I enter into the command line to compile:

```
C:\>javac -classpath .;c:\GridWorldCode\gridworld.jar; C:\GridWorldCode\projects\firstProject\BugRunner.java
```

Then, I enter this to run it:

```
C:\>java -classpath .;c:\GridWorldCode\gridworld.jar; C:\GridWorldCode\projects\firstProject\BugRunner
```

Please help, this very beginner problem is very frustrating. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's because BugRunner is buried in subdirectories and so interpreting it as a package hierarchy (gridworldcode.projects.firstproject.bugrunner).

1. Change to the same directory bugrunner.java is in.
2. Run javac *from there* and specify just bugrunner.java to the compiler not the full absolute path
3. Do the same when running with java.

Hope that made sense. Having trouble formatting or typing out full examples on my phone.